# Sabre java SOAP client

Tags: java, soap, soapui, sabre

I am trying to develop a java SOAP based client integrating the Sabre(https://developer.sabre.com) hotels booking services. When i try to execute the test services in SOAPUI, it is always failing and getting the following response.

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">123123</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">999999</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>ipcc</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>conversationID</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>677671ee-ed04-4bf2-bfcb-e12c54e6aad4@19</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2016-01-30T16:50:15</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthenticationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Authentication failed</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED</StackTrace>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Can anyone able to guide me on this?

Regards,
Mayuran

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your credentials (username, password, organization, domain) submitted in your call to SessionCreateRQ may not be correct.

Make sure the values are correct and you are pointing to the appropriate environment (you normally get credentials for the customer acceptance testing environment at first: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments )

Comment: effectively, after changing my credentials to incorrect values, and using SessionCreateRQ, I get exactly the same error, so you may want to validate them with Sabre.

You can contact Sabre using this form:
https://developer.sabre.com/contact

Or via email to webservices.support@sabre.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like we need to get proper license before calling SOAP services